# Having Trouble with Flex-box Code

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having trouble getting my navigation buttons to collapse into a column and in a particular order.

I'm having trouble with getting the navigation tabs and the two logos (which are on the same row) to not spill out of the container when the screen is shrunken. To aid in better understanding, I have the particular row highlighted in yellow, as well as the container outlined with a 1px black border.

I'm having trouble getting the background image of the park to fill the entire row, up the edge of the container. As of now, it has huge margins. I've been trying to fix these problems for hours! Here is the link to my Code Pen: https://codepen.io/IDCoder/pen/rGWeEE?editors=1100. Furthermore, this is the Code Pen that I used to structure my flex-box syntax: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/gpqmaR?editors=1100. **I placed the corresponding html and css code for this Code Pen below my Code Pen code**. Thanks in advance for your help! Cheers!

```
.container-fluid{
border: 1px solid #000000;
overflow: hidden;
}


.row-one{
display: flex;
}


.Logo-one{
padding: 3px;
}

.Logo-two{
padding: 3px;
}


 ul.navigation{
 flex:1;
 justify-content:space-between; 
 font: bold 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 margin: 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 float: right;
 text-align center;
 /*border: 1px solid green;*/
 /*overflow: hidden;*/  
}




ul.navigation:nth-child(LOG IN){
  order: 1;
}

ul.navigation:nth-child(BUY A HOME){
  order: 2;
}

ul.navigation:nth-child(SELL A HOME){
  order: 3;
}

ul.navigation:nth-child(CONTACT US){
  order: 4;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 100%){
.navigation{
flex-direction: column;
}

  ul.navigation:nth-child(BUY A HOME){
    order: 1;
  }

  ul.navigation:nth-child(SELL A HOME){
    order: 2;
  }

  ul.navigation:nth-child(CONTACT US){
    order: 3;
  }

  ul.navigation:nth-child(LOG IN){
    order: 4;
  }

}


.navigation li {
  display: inline-block;  
}

.navigation a {
  background: #395870;
  background: linear-gradient(#49708f, #293f50);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation a:hover {
  background: #314b0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
.navigation li:first-child a {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
.navigation li:last-child a {
  border-right: 0;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}



.row.two{
background-image: url(https://s26.postimg.org/j1h75tfs9/Hyde_Park_Chicago_Harold_Washington_Park.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    max-width: 1600;
        height: 550px;
        margin: auto;  
}

 .floater.box{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity: .45;
    max-width: 85%;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}


<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ms.Jane Equities Management Corp</title>
  </head>  
      <body> 
        <div class="container-fluid">

          <!-- Top Box -->
          <div class="row-one" style="background-color:yellow">
            <div class="Logo-one" >
              <img src="https://s26.postimg.org/iqkxecqnd/Coldwell_Banker-_Logo_RS1.jpg" width="150" height="82"/>
            </div>
            <div class="Logo-two">
              <img src="https://s26.postimg.org/iqkxecqnd/Coldwell_Banker-_Logo_RS1.jpg" width="150" height="82"/> 
            </div>
            <div class ="navigation buttons">                       
                  <ul class="navigation">
                    <li id="NAV-ONE"><a href="#">LOG IN</a></li>
                    <li id="NAV-TWO"><a href="#">BUY A HOME</a></li>
                    <li id="NAV-THREE"><a href="#">SELL A HOME</a></li>
                    <li id="NAV-FOUR"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                 </ul>           
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Middle Box -->
          <div class="row two">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="floater box">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Bottom Box -->
          <div class="row three">
          </div>

        </div>
      </body>
<html>
```

Below, is the code from the Code Pen where I got my flex-box syntax from:

CSS Code:

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.box:first-child {
  order: 1;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  order: 2;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  order: 3;
}

@media screen and (max-width:760px) {
  .wrap {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .box:nth-child(2) {
    order: 3;
  }
  .box:nth-child(3) {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: Hi @rjustin, the goals are stated in the first post. The second post was a response to an answer by Frish. My goal is to have the navigation buttons collapse into a column and with a particular order, when the screen size is shrunken. Also, I need my background picture, in the second row, to fill the row, all the way to the edges of the container (which is clarified by a 1px black border). Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: To me, this question is looking unclear too. If it is connected to another question, you could edit and extended the other question. If this is a new question, please try to make it understandable without having to read the old question.

Comment: Hi @ventiseis, I edited my question.

Comment: @codebwoy is this what you are looking for https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrNoeJ

Comment: @rjustin, very close!.....except that the two logos and the navigation bar buttons are on a separate row, not floating over the background image below. The background image is on a separate row. The buttons you have does collapse into a column right, but I want them to collapse around 300px - 500px and a different order. Thanks for your help so far man!

Comment: @codebwoy https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrNoeJ Do you want them to only collapse when its 300-500px?

Comment: @rjustin, yes......for smartphones. Try it on your smartphone and post a screen-shot...

Comment: @codebwoy Give another try with what ive given you, youre on the right track with the media query and child https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrNoeJ hopefully this points you in the right direction

Comment: @rjustin, why did you use this link: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexboxgrid/6.3.1/flexboxgrid.min.css" /> ....do I need this? Because usually I don't like to use framework links as for the possibility that one day the link may no longer work....??/

Comment: @codebwoy I used that because you didnt include any flexbox libraries. Your fear is possible but unlikely and you wont make it terribly far without any 3rd party libraries.

Comment: @codebwoy Have you looked at maybe using bootstrap? it does navbars just like you want in a responsive and widely used manner.

Comment: oh ok thanks @rjustin